# In our application, while downloading PDF file getting "Failed - Network Error". The same functionality is working fine in IE and FF

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, general-network-error

In our application, while downloading PDF file getting "Failed - Network Error". The same functionality is working fine in IE and FF.

Chrome version:  62.0.3202.75

Operating system:  Windows 10, 64 bit

[image: In attached screen shot you can see in the bottom of the page lest side, we are getting "Failed - Network Error"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution, in latest versions of Chrome after adding "Transfer-Encoding" header it starts working.

Response.AddHeader("Transfer-Encoding", "identity");